# SQL Server 2008 Filestream Win32 error without a network cable!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

I have a SQL Server 2008 database utilizing Filestreaming and all works fine and dandy apart from under one very strange circumstance.  If i have my database on, say a laptop, on a locally installed version of SQL Server 2008 and am connected to the network all works fine.  If i unplug the network cable, after a while the SqlFileStream class fails to initialize with a Win32 exception (everything else about connecting to the database works fine).  If i start fresh without a network cable it will not work with the same error. If i plug a network cable in even with no network connectivity it works... take it out, nothing.

I'm connecting to the filestream in the usual documented method

```
SqlFileStream fileStream = new SqlFileStream(path, 
                                             context, 
                                             FileAccess.ReadWrite,  
                                             FileOptions.SequentialScan, 
                                             0);
```

geting the path and context from a stored procedure which generates them in the following

```
SELECT Data.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() 
  FROM dbo.DocumentFiles
 WHERE [File_ID] = @FileId
```

I'm getting the following error when creating the SqlFileStream instance

> Win32Exception occurred The network
>   location cannot be reached.  For more
>   information about network
>   troubleshooting, see Windows help.

No inner exception.

I have tried so many things to resolve the issue with no luck.  no one in google-land seems to have the same issue so obviously something silly I'm doing. If anyone can shed any light on this i would be most grateful.

James

Comment: Have you tried changing the Server on the connection to "."

Comment: yes, i have tried lots of different combinations of the connection string.  Different network libraries, user types, trusted connections, server names and instances.... seems to be more of a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. It looks like your network interface goes down when you unplug your cable. When it happens TCP/IP stack goes down as well since there's no more available interfaces left. I suggest you to to install the MS Loopback adapter, this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013) explains how to do it in Windows XP; it is easy to google about how to do it in other OSes. Do not forget to assign a **static** IP to it after installation, private address like 192.168.1.x would be sufficient. Since loopback adapter is a virtual one, it is in "Up" state all the time, even when you unplug your cable and it prevents Windows from shutting TCP stack down.

Comment: Would this still be the case if i'm using named pipes as the network library?

Comment: I followed the instructions (i was returning the loop back address when i was pinging myself) and now all is working.  Thank you very much for offering this suggestion.  This was really bugging me!  This does seem to be a bit of a short coming in the filestream method in 2008 though?

Comment: No, I don't think that this is a shortcoming in the FileStream method,
it looks like you're using TCP/IP to connect to SQL server, and when TCP/IP goes down the connection stops working too. No wonder that SqlFileStream can't retrieve any data, hence the exception. I believe if you start using shared memory or named pipes as a transport, you will no longer need MS loopback adapter, but of course, you will be able to connect to a local instance of SQL server then.

Comment: This is very strange as i am using named pipes.  This is one of things i tried changing between tcp/ip, named pipes, shared memory and this made no difference.  

Many thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, James. I am glad that my solution helped you, but it left me wonder how TCP/IP affected shared memory :)

Comment: I suppose it may have something to do with SqlFileStream not actually using the database connection but using a share name set up to access to the filestream location.  

the Data.PathName() returns a logical path and is set up on the machines shares.  I assume when the tcp/ip goes down the shares stop working as well.  this is regardless of the sql server connection, which is using shared memory in my case!

Might this explain it? or am i still missing something?

Comment: @James: "I assume when the tcp/ip goes down the shares stop working as well" -- I think that explains everything! SQL server obviously needs a way to retrieve the requested data, which is impossible when tcp/ip is down. Sharing is based on SMB (Server Message Block) protocol, which in turn is based on tcp/ip. No TCP-->No Shared folder access-->No data-->Exception. Thank you for the interesting question, James!